# Truck overheating and affecting the heater blowing could air occasionally

Tags: maintenance, oldsmobile

I have a 2001 Oldsmobile Bravada with about 160,000 miles. At first I could hear a faint gurgling sound from the right front side under the hood when I’d stop and go. Then about a month later my truck started running hot (at 230°F or so), so I checked the coolant even though I had just put some in two weeks prior, and there was hardly any. I refilled and it was going like crazy. And on top of that, the heater in my truck goes cold when the gauge starts to go over 200°. When it starts to get close to the red, the heat suddenly goes hot and my gauge goes back down to around 150°. Also, when I’m on the highway it switches from hot to cold a lot less than in town, or does it slower.

There is a leak: it kind of looked like oil, but I use Dex-Cool antifreeze, so it’s red.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you actually asked a question. Are you asking what you should do about your coolant leak? If you put coolant in your truck, and the coolant disappears, you have a coolant leak. You need to fix the coolant leak or have a shop find and fix the coolant leak,  or your truck is going to overheat and stop working permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the coolant leak and see if that solves the other problems.  If the coolant level is low, it won't circulate through the heater coil and the radiator fans won't go on.  If it boils, the steam will roll through the system, heating the heater coil and activating the fans (cooling it back down) and .  That's my theory at least.  It can't be good for anything, so I would fix that leak ASAP.